# Convergence problem in polymer - silicon structural analysis

Tags: sensors, ansys-apdl

I'm trying to model a capacitive force sensor with a bilayer configuration of polymer - Si on Mechanical APDL 16.2 .

I have a 0.2 mm layer of Si deposited on 0.005 mm of polyimide polymer. My goal is to find out the the length change in polyimide for an exerted force of 3 mN. For that purpose, I plot the displacement curve along x direction (origin to the edge). However, I obtain a nonlinear result.

I can't understand the origin of this nonlinearity. In my opinion, the polymer has to obey Hooke's law. What could be its reason?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f3ad42a0824657714d818ac81cc20838) is the model code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com is a better place for anonymous sharing of code snippets.